# Can we add vertical scroll in text input (react js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have tried below some of the sol. but didn't worked.
Here is the codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/react-input-example-forked-zgwpgs?file=/src/index.js which I have tried.

If we can't add scroll in TextInput then what we can use to show values with scroll ?

Comment: Check this. https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-textarea-tag

Comment: @ChanHyeok-Im Can we add html element as value in textarea is there any way ?

Comment: Add contenteditable="true" on div for display html element.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "textarea" tag

Comment: Can we add html element as value in textarea is there any way ?